# can Dijkstra's algorithm be considered under linear programming?

Tags: data-structures, dijkstra

i know that Dijkstra's algorithm is a graph search algorithm.but can it be considered under linear programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can form the shortest path problem as a linear program problem. So basically yes:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Linear_programming_formulation